# Mapping Excel sheet to database using hibernate

Tags: java, excel, hibernate, orm, apache-poi

I have some master data to populate in the database and this is a one time activity done at the time of the very first execution. I have decided to maintain the data in multiple sheets in an excel file. There are some relationships in the database which i have to care of in the excel sheet. This sheet will be read using an API(POI) and the data will be persisted using hibernate.

Please suggest if this is the right approach or there are better ways to handle this? Is there any other way to dump the excel into the database using hibernate(need a single excel file and support 5 types of databases)?

Answer (score 0):

Using excel and POI you can achieve this but as you are asking for other way so here it is:

If you are sure that this is one time activity then you can use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property which will execute .sql file at the time of DB creation.

Add hibernate `property hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` in your hibernate configuration. Change `hibernate.hbm2ddl.aut`o property to `create`. value of `property hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` is an SQL file which is @ /classes folder.

Session factory bean will look like

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">initial_data.sql</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Amogh, 
The reason i had to move to some other format is that the SQL syntax changes with the change in the database type. To support say 5 types of databases i will have to manage 5 different .sql files.

Comment: Also i would like to know how one can preserve  the relationships in an excel file when porting data into the database

Comment: @Sushant as per my experience it's quite tough to maintain relationship in excel, you can learn Excel data model and relationship using [Pivot Table](http://blogs.office.com/2012/08/23/introduction-to-the-data-model-and-relationships-in-excel-2013/)

Comment: @Sushant I can understand the problem about multiple DBs but if you follow ANSI SQL syntax you can prepare a single .sql file which will work on all DB, I guess.